# URL Mapping - Change Default.aspx to virtual page after first page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, url-mapping

i want to have virtual page instead of Default.aspx like :
`www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx`   ->    `www.mydomain.com/Virual-Page`
after opening my url in browser.

How could i change web.config to get that goal?

The codes below in web.config does not work....

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/Virtual-Page" mappedUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
</urlMappings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this package: [ASP.NET Friendly URL's](https://aspnetfriendlyurls.codeplex.com) how to implement can be found on [Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

Add this to your global.asax file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Add a reference at the top of the Global.asax file as shown below:

```
using System.Web.Routing;
```

this automatically rewrites your URL.

If you want to keep default.aspx, use the URL Mapping:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/Virtual-Page" mappedUrl="~/default.aspx" />
</urlMappings>
```

Add a rewrite rule to redirect your base URL, with [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to Virtual-Page">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="~/Virtual-Page" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

If you can't use URL rewrite add a response.redirect in the global.asax begin request:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://localhost/Virtual-Page"))
    {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://localhost/", "http://localhost/Virtual-Page"));
    }
```

Comment: so how can i fix start page using with that?

Comment: I've added the code. If you want to change the start up page you can do this like I say in the answer. You don't need URL mapping for this.

Comment: your answer is explaining URL Routing. i test all of these -> URL Mapping, URL Rewriting, URL Mapping. all of these can map goal url to virtual path. but my problem is for Default.aspx home page and i don't want to change it's name at all.

Comment: please show me a simple way to change Default.aspx to Vitual-Page. thats all... renaming that page is not my answer!

Comment: The code you use works for this, make sure you go to domain.com/virtual-page in the browser

Comment: but user always type domain.com and don't know any thing about Vitual-Page, also i don't want any extra changes in iis.

Comment: I've added a rewrite rule you can use to redirect the base URL to the Virtual-Page

Comment: They haven't installed URL Rewrite on my host's IIS. so how can i add it's dll to my project's references without any dependent to iis?

Comment: you could do a redirect in the global.asax begin request